# XPCOM CPP code fail to find an existing key in the registry

Tags: c++, firefox, registry, xpcom

Here is a simplified example of a code I use in my XPCOM CPP DLL to check if a key exists in the registry.
It checks for the existance of 2 keys: `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft` and `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microso` both exist with the same permissions, but the first one is found by this code and the second one is not... any idea why?

```
nsCOMPtr<nsIWindowsRegKey> regKey = 
    do_CreateInstance("@mozilla.org/windows-registry-key;1");
if (!regKey) {
    log("can't create @mozilla.org/windows-registry-key;1");
    return -1;
}
NS_NAMED_LITERAL_STRING(key2,
   "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft");
if (NS_FAILED(regKey->Open(nsIWindowsRegKey::ROOT_KEY_CLASSES_ROOT,
                          key2, nsIWindowsRegKey::ACCESS_QUERY_VALUE))) {

     // FAILED
    LOG("regKey:: no such key");

}

NS_NAMED_LITERAL_STRING(key1,
   "SOFTWARE\\Microso");
if (NS_FAILED(regKey->Open(nsIWindowsRegKey::ROOT_KEY_CLASSES_ROOT,
                          key1, nsIWindowsRegKey::ACCESS_QUERY_VALUE))) {

    // FAILED
    LOG("regKey:: no such key");

}
```

*EDIT:* To make it clear, I've created a registry key myself, called `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microso` and I can access it through `regedit`.

Comment: Are you using an x86 Firefox build (the usual one) on x64 Windows?

Answer (score 0):

nsIWindowsRegKey.Open is implemented via RegOpenKeyEx WinAPI function. This function requires existing relative path passed as argument and does not support templates. If there is no exactly same path in the registry, it falls. **SOFTWARE\Microsoft** is exists in the HKLM root space, **HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microso** is not.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is most likely that you are viewing the registry with the x64 regedit and then expecting Firefox to have the same view. However, regedit is an x64 application whereas the usual Firefox builds are x86 and run inside the 32-bit subsystem (via [WoW64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WoW64)). When an x86 application accesses the `HKLM\Software` key it gets redirected to `HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node`. You can run `c:\Windows\SysWOW64\regedit.exe` instead of `c:\Windows\regedit.exe` to see the view of the registry that an x86 application gets.

So your XPCOM component is actually trying to access `HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft` and `HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microso` - and the former exists while the latter doesn't. If you want to access the "real" registry key instead, you have to pass the [`WOW64_64` flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIWindowsRegKey#Access_constants) in the third parameter of `nsIWindowsRegKey.open()` (it corresponds to the [`KEY_WOW64_64KEY` flag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724878%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that can be passed to the [`RegOpenKeyEx` WinAPI function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724897%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)):

```
NS_NAMED_LITERAL_STRING(key1,
   "SOFTWARE\\Microso");
if (NS_FAILED(regKey->Open(nsIWindowsRegKey::ROOT_KEY_CLASSES_ROOT, key1,
                          nsIWindowsRegKey::ACCESS_QUERY_VALUE | nsIWindowsRegKey::WOW64_64))) {

    // FAILED
    LOG("regKey:: no such key");

}
```